# How to add this information to an array?

Tags: c

I've got this project in C and the code looks like this.

```
BOOL Commands(LPBYTE command, DWORD size)
{
wchar_t params[MAXCHAR];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, (LPCCH)command, size, params, size);

wchar_t *bufferoon;
bufferoon = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * size);
wcscpy(bufferoon, params);


wchar_t buf2[MAXCHAR], *ptr;
int i;
wchar_t a[MAXCHAR];

for (ptr = wcstok(bufferoon, L","); ptr != NULL; ptr = wcstok(NULL, L","))
{
    CWA(lstrcpyW, kernel32, buf2, ptr);
    for (i = 0; i < lstrlenW(buf2); i++)
    {

        if (buf2[i] == '=' )
        {
            wcscpy(a + i, buf2 + i + 1);
            MessageBoxW(0, a + i, 0, 0);    
        }

    }

}


free(bufferoon);

CWA(Sleep, kernel32, 100);
return 1;
}
```

It gets a string from a PHP page and then splits it, removes the "=" and some junk before the "=" and  and displays the important datas in MessageBoxes one by one and it works well.

However, instead of showing it in messageboxes, I want to create an array with all the data.

For example, some of the data returned as "a + i" will include:

```
 1. https
 2. //test.com/test.doc
 3. H3IG2IOUFG23IOFGU2H3
 Etc.
```

I want to create an array, so I can use it to make if-statements.

For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
if(strarray[1] == L"https") 
{ 
MessageBoxW(0,L"Element 1 equals HTTPS",0,0);
}
```

However, after trying a million things for hours and hours, I have still no clue, so I am asking you guys on StackOverflow as a last resort.

Does anyone have an idea? My brain is fried by now, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is right, forgot that (C# took over my conscience... :)) However, I still need to put all those strings to an array so I can use for example strcmp( strarray[1] blabla), so my question remains unchanged, I think. Thanks for your awareness though, Melpomene.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array, you need to know the size. You have two choices:

1) Allocate an array of N elements using `malloc` (just pick some number N), populate the array, and increment your size variable. If size exceeds N, you will need to `realloc` with a bigger N.

2) Perform two loops. The first loop counts the number of array elements. After the first loop ends, use `malloc` to allocate the array knowing the size. Then perform a second loop to populate the array.

```
int N=0;
wchar_t *saved = wcsdup(bufferoon);
for (ptr = wcstok(bufferoon, L","); ptr != NULL; ptr = wcstok(NULL, L","))
{
    for (i = 0; i < lstrlenW(ptr); i++)
    {
        if (ptr[i] == '=' )
        {   
            ++N;
            break;
        }
    }
}
int j=0;
wchar_t **a = malloc(N*sizeof(*a));
for (ptr = wcstok(saved, L","); ptr != NULL; ptr = wcstok(NULL, L","))
{
    for (i = 0; i < lstrlenW(ptr); i++)
    {
        if (ptr[i] == '=' )
        {   
            a[j++] = wcsdup(ptr+i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
free(saved);
```

Comment: The size of the array will be 7, without changes and the data will be given in a standard sequence. I tried the code you gave me before (which has been removed now) but I couldn't get it to work. :(

Comment: Ok. `N=7; wchar_t **a = malloc(N*sizeof(*a));`

Comment: I tried adding that, however I had to change it to:     int N = 7; wchar_t **a = (wchar_t**)malloc(N * sizeof(*a)); to work without errors, I hope that isn't something bad I've done.  I still have no clue how to populate that and make it work like an array though, I am kind of new from C and coming from C#.. Could you maybe repost the code you've removed? It seemed like good code

Comment: You'll also need to use `wcsdup` to allocate memory for each `wchar_t *`. This will allocate and copy at the same time. `wcscpy` will only copy.

Comment: I tried to make it work like this: https://paste.ee/r/g4J0W/0, and if I were able to reset the "str" value every time it looped, I suppose it should work. However, using    memset(str, 0, MAXCHAR)     makes the program stop. No idea how to do this any other way anymore.

Comment: I removed the code because you are doing something weird with your `a+i` that you shouldn't be doing (that I didn't catch) and so the code I posted would not work anyway. I'll try to edit my post with a solution.

Comment: I see. Yes, you are right about that. Let me explain. The data from the PHP pages comes into the program in a format like this: "cid={ABCDE-12345-NADJAS-232D2I},ti=AAAC723G23GD0AAA,name=John". I only need the stuff behind the "=" symbol, so my friend made this function where the data gets split at the comma-delimiter, and then it does nothing untill it finds an "=" and then it takes all the data + 1, the  +1 to avoid the "=" being stored aswell. I understand what he did but I don't think it is the best solution, however I couldn't think of any better solution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help me, I really appreciate it. I tried to implement the code you gave me, however, the output is now a messagebox displaying Chinese-like characters. The way I implemented the code: https://paste.ee/r/owHg4/0 The window which pops up: http://prntscr.com/h3oe3e Am I doing anything wrong? I only have to import the second part of your code right? Since I already know the amount of elements in the array?

Comment: Sorry. I messed up the `a[i]` too. Edited.

Comment: I turned my PC off, it's getting really late. I will try your function tomorrow and update how it went! Thanks once again :) and good night.

Comment: Hello, I just tried your function and implemented it like this: https://paste.ee/r/sQCKU/0 This returns the string properly exactly like I need it, however afterwards the program shuts down/crashes/terminates itself.. It stops without reason, this function should be looping continuously so that is kind of a problem. Thanks though, I could've never came this far myself!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue of the program stopping itself?

Comment: @Tsukiri, The issue is somewhere else in your code you did not provide.  There is no way anyone here can help you without the rest of the program.  Honestly though, the code you initially provided shows a fundamental lack of understanding.  I suggest you study.  If we do your assignment for you, you will not learn.  You need to learn how to write and debug your code yourself.  And do not copy code from others you do not FULLY UNDERSTAND.

Comment: You might be right... I just wanted to make this function work because once I got the data to an array it won't be very hard to finish the project.. I am sorry. I am sure though that the error is in this code since the project is something which was coded by someone else and it did loop without stopping before I put in the code you typed above